# Angular App in CORS Losing Session

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, session

I have two domains:

- `http://localhost:9000` / My AngularJS App created with Yeoman
- `http://localhost`/ My PHP app created with CodeIgniter

My Angular app do `$http.post` to autenticate in the PHP app and save a session to indetify the user as logged, but, when i try recovery the user informations stored in the CI Session, just don't exists.

How i can allow the AngularJS app access the session and don't lose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your PHP app is configured to support CORS, then Angular `$httpProvider` needs to be configured as follows...

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
```

And then to allow response cookies to be set, `withCredentials` must be true...

```
$http.post(url, {withCredentials: true, ...})
```

Lastly, you may have to tweak the cookie domain and path to be accessible across subdomains of your TLD.  For example, if your CORS server resides at `api.foo.com`, then it will likely set cookies on `api.foo.com` by default, and your client app on `awesome-app.foo.com` will be denied access to these cookies.  Of course for security reasons, you not want your client app to read the session cookies of the API.

Hope this helps.  Good luck.